# combining rows in result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this data table:

```
+-ID-+-sensorID-+----date---+-value-+
| 1  | 1        |'some date'|  20   |
| 2  | 1        |'some date'|  15   |
| 3  | 1        |'some date'|  18   |
| 4  | 2        |'some date'|  40   |
| 5  | 2        |'some date'|  68   |
| 6  | 2        |'some date'|  55   |
```

Now I want to create an array like this in php:

```
date - value sensorID(1) - value sensorID(2)
```

I also need something to show whenever a date has a single sensor value:

```
[date] => 01-01-2014 [value] => 50 [value] => 60
[date] => 02-01-2014 [value] => 20 [value] => 30
[date] => 03-01-2014 [value] => null [value] => 55
[date] => 04-01-2014 [value] => 20 [value] => 33
```

How can I do this efficiently in some simple steps? Otherwise I would just create a result for ID 1 and ID 2 or run my function twice on the complete array.

Comment: i assume that you are using `ID` as `sensor ID` if so then use `Join` in your query to `Join` this table with itself and save results in array

Comment: @NaveedYousaf 'ID' is the primary key of the data itself 'sensorID' is the linked ID to the sensor in my DB. So i can join a table by itself? Also i need something like 'null' for the value if a value is missing at a specific date for a 'sensorID'.

Comment: Just `SELECT *` and populate the array in php: `foreach $row, $result[$row['date']][$row['sensorID']] = $row['value']`

Comment: just use `Left Outer join` or `Right outer join` in your query you will `join` on the basis of `ID == sensorID` it will bring whole data if in case you do not have data against `ID == 6` it will insert default object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all the data in one run and construct the array in PHP:

```
// do the mysql query stuff >> $result (array of all rows in db)
$data = array();
foreach ($result AS $row) {
  if (!isset($data[$row['date']])) {
    $data[$row['date']] = array('sensor1' => null, 'sensor2' => null);
  }
  $data[$row['date']]['sensor' . $row['sensorID']] = $row['value'];
}
```

Result would be something like

```
$data = array(
  '01-01-2014' => array('sensor1' => 50, 'sensor2' => 60),
  '02-01-2014' => array('sensor1' => 20, 'sensor2' => 30),
  '03-01-2014' => array('sensor1' => null, 'sensor2' => 55),
  '04-01-2014' => array('sensor1' => 20, 'sensor2' => 33)
);
```

Comment: I might be tired but I cannot get to loop this array and get both the values and the date associated with the values. the date is the key of the array but if I 'foreach($data as $d)' I cannot get key($d). I can just output the values.

Comment: Nevermind, i'm just tired :), Thanks a lot this worked like a charm.